# A Roman-technology clock run by slaves - how to make it accurate

Tags: technology, ancient-history, time-keeping

In a land similar to the Roman Empire, slaves are used to drive machinery. Mostly this is a matter of getting them to pull carts or wind handles.

The Emperor wants a clock that is accurate to the minute, powered by slaves.

With the technology of Ancient Rome and unlimited slave-power, how can such a clock be accurately regulated?

Let us suppose that the clock has a face similar to a modern-day analog clock.

---

**Notes**

The clock cannot be regulated by referring to another clock. It must be self-regulating.

Water power, sand-timers, wound-springs etc. are not to be used directly to power the clock - just slave manual power. However an (unpowered?) mechanism will be need to regulate the machine.

Comment: The Romans had clocks. Water clocks, sand clocks, weight driven clocks, burning clocks. The power required by a clock movement is trivial -- you don't need a slave, you need a small mouse. What they *didn't* have was enough knowledge of physics to make an accurate clock. They did not know about isochronous oscillations. The question is about the wrong problem.

Comment: The reason the Emperor want *his* clock to be slave-powered is to display his wealth. It is a big clock to be displayed somewhere prominent. The more impressive the mechanism, the better.

Comment: The small mouse is needed if the clock is *very* large. For a normal sized clock you need a juvenile ant. (Clock movements are extremely well-balanced, to the limit of mechanical technology. The entire point is to minimize the power required to work the movement, so that the imperfections and variability of the power source have as small an effect as possible on the accuracy of the clock.) But, since the poor Romans lived long before Galileo, they did not know of any self-regulating natural phenomenon. That small oscillations of a pendulum are isochronous was discovered in 1602.

Comment: If it was actually considered a clock and usable on cloudy days, I'd add an answer about training the slaves to stand in a Gnomon pattern (think cheerleaders) and make a sundial

Comment: Dear downvoters: the question isn't about Rome per se, it's about a Rome-like (Romanesque!) fictional world. It does not matter what the real Romans knew or didn't know. The only issue here, for us, is how to get these *other Romans* to make their slave clock run regular.

Comment: If its just a show of wealth, why not have a real clock somewhere, and then just have the slaves move the hands of a giant 500m display clock, to match the time on the smaller real clock. Accurate time, and needless show of wealth and power achieved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One possibility would be this set-up, all components being available to your parallel world Roman Imperials:

**Component I:**  is the temporal regulation mechanism.  Deep within the works of the *Horologon*, is a water cistern that is kept full from municipal water supplies (the Aqueduct). Pipes bring water down to a valve that is set by the engineers to flow at a certain rate. The water itself is brought up into a marble statue of a water nymph and is ejected from her left nipple at a constant rate. The water so ejected squirts onto a small water wheel which thus rotates at a constant rate. Two of the water wheel's buckets have projections that strike a small brass chime held by a bronze satyr at the wheel's base.

**Component II:** is the slave regulating mechanism.  This component consists of a slave, two wooden mallets and two bronze nakers (a kind of drum). The slave, taking his cues from the satyr's chime, beats out a lively rhythm on the nakers which will regulate the slaves that actually operate the horologon itself. The rhythms vary by the hour, and close attention paid by passersby will immediately tell them, just by listening, what the hour is, even if they don't look up at the horologon's clever display.

**Component III:** are the slave tableaus.  This is all part of the magic of Romanesque time keeping: the day being divided into fifteen hours of the clock, based on the calculated number of chime beats on Midsummer's day, there are therefore fifteen tableaux visible on the horologon's portico. The figures in each tableau are dressed in characteristic fashion of a particular region of the Empire and the slaves in each tableau dance in a fashion characteristic of that region. Other slaves, the *tempora magistri*, or "conductors", beat time along with the nakers by tapping their feet and striking the floor of the portico with their batons.  Baton strikes are carefully counted and choreographed with the rhythms of the nakers to occur every half minute, first one strike then a double-strike. Every minute, or every double-strike of the conductors' baton therefore denotes one minute. At this moment, the tableau advances slightly around the portico.

**Component IIIJ:** is the horologon's display.  Resting upon a great toothed rondel of hard wood at the centre of the tableau is a similarly toothed rondel from which radiates fifteen long spars with red legionary shields at the end of each, upon which are painted large numbers: J, IJ, IIJ, IIIJ, etc. up to XV.

**Component V:** is the housing.  Naturally, the Emperor wishes to help the people of the Eternal City tell time, else why build a public horologon at all? But more importantly, he wishes to make a grand and opulent public display of the whole matter. Sure, any Marcus Aurelius in the street can look up at the Sun and say, oh, it's a little after noon. But the Emperor wants to make sure that not only his own subjects, but also traders from distant lands and embassies from rival empires and visiting dignitaries alike are awed by the cunning engineering and obviously vast wealth of the Empire.  To do this, the entire horologon is housed within a marble temple like building, perhaps on the end of one of the basilicas. The beauty of its painted statuary and mythological stonework is a feast for the eyes; and all eyes will be drawn to the huge arched *skene*, the stage where the tableaux play out.

**Component VJ:** is the general orchestration of the horologon.  All well and good, but how does one actually tell time? Quite simply, if one is sufficiently literate, one can simply read the numbers on the dial. As the big **XIJ** moves across the stage, you know it's twelve o'clock. If you're clever and you notice the evenly spaced markings along the base of the stage, you'll see that each time the conductor double-strikes his baton, the cartouche moves from one marking to the next.  And, again, if you're literate, you'll notice that these markings are labelled: *prima, secunda, tertia, etc.*  The big numbers indicate hours of the clock, the small numbers indicate minutes.

But the wise observer will note the horologon does much more than count minutes and hours.  Indeed, the wise Emperor has devised the tableaux in such a way that each set of costumes and each set of dances is constantly changed over the course of time. Every day, the timed syllable chanting of the slaves, with its calculated number of syllables per line & strophe, corresponding to the passage of minutes, changes -- one day, hymns to the Moon or the Stars or to Istar or Ares; every two weeks, the dances change slightly and every month the costumes change as well. Every three months, the over-arching theme changes.  Thus, the observant student of the imperial horologon can tell you what day, what hour and minute and in what fortnight and season you are currently in, all by observing and listening to what the horlogon of Emperor Minimus is telling!

Comment: This is how the Remans in my own world went about it, anyway!

Comment: When you remove the gilded lilly, what's left of this answer is remarkably simple and, IMHO, the best answser.  The slaves keep a cistern filled with water.  The sistern can be made of a central, deep column and a larger, wider bowl at the top so the pressure remains reasonably constant while the water level shifts up and down with human error.  The result is a constant and predictable flow of water that can be used to drive gearing of any complexity known to the Romans and easily calibrated to any desired timekeeping condition.  Boom, baby.  Well done Elemtilas.

Comment: Thank you much, @JBH! I, of course, appreciate the gilded lily aspect of this answer. The "clock" proper is simply constant water flow and a chime to help the human mind keep track of the time factor with respect to water flow. But, hey, this is Rome! And wealthy Romans thrive on opulent displays of wealth and power! Plus, I needed something for all the slaves to occupy their time.

Comment: This is very impressive. The Emperor even now has his advisors consulting about this possibility.

Comment: @JBH The bowl wouldn't help with precision: pressure depends on the total volume of water above (per surface at a given height), not of height. So a column and a bowl of the same volume would generate the same pressure. Better have a long, thin column and some way to keep the water level more or less constant.

Comment: @Eth, that doesn't make any sense.  Water pressure is simply the amount of water above a point.  If a big box or bowl existed above the column, any water not directly over the column wouldn't contribute to water pressure at the base of the column.  By maximizing surface area vs. column volume, you avoid the need for the water delivery precision - which is the point.  Without a spring to create a primitive pressure regulator it's the best accuracy-vs-complexity trade-off.

Comment: @JBH Weird, I am certain I read otherwise in a manual a decade ago, and I remember being quite surprised because it indeed didn't seem to make sense. Checking it now though, it seems you're right and that stupid book was wrong. To retrace it is another thing, though...

Comment: If your cistern has a overflow at the top you can precisely maintain the water column height, and therefore pressure without any complex regulators.

Comment: Well I'm glad to say that the Emperor has approved your plans and will put them into action very shortly. You are also invited to a feast in your honour and you will be awarded a sizeable purse of gold. (I haven't ever given a bounty before so I'll have to work out how to when one is available. Presumably I can do it retrospectively???)

Comment: Ha! Dinner with the Emperor could very well end messily!  (a whole nother question!) ... ah... I think I'll be out of the country! ;))

Comment: "The Emperor wants a clock that is accurate to the minute" <- a water clock is precise but not accurate.  Unless you sync it to a solar clock, this answer fails this requirement.  If you put two of these clocks on opposite sides of town, they will often be at least 10 minutes out of sync if you try to start your day by eyeballing the sunrise.

Answer (score 7):

## With a pendulum

The quirk being that neither the pendulum nor the need for accurate time keeping had been invented in the period you're asking for, but gearing was already in use, the basic physics of a pendulum regulator could follow well enough.

Comment: I'm not sure how they make the pendulum swing regularly. Surely a slave would have to push it. That is subject to error.  Do you have a reference that indicates how the Romans were using gearing - that sounds interesting.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, the pendulum is driven by the clock itself, the slave just walks round his hamster wheel and everything follows from there.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK That's why grandfather clocks have both weights and a pendulum. The clockwork and pendulum are powered by the weights as they slowly fall, the pendulum is just there to keep time. As long as the slave regularly resets the weights, or provides some other form of hamster wheel power, the clock would run regularly.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, the source you're looking for for gears is the [Antikythera mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antikythera_mechanism) this could be the work of a lone raving genius, but it shows the principle of gears was known in the period.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: In 1602 Galileo discovered that the period of oscillation of a pendulum is almost independent of the amplitude of the oscillations, as long as the oscillations are small. *You don't need to do anything for the pendulum to swing regularly* -- it does that all by itself. The small power input is needed to compensate for energy loss due to friction in the mechanism. A large grandfather clock uses about 0.1 milliwatts of power. A huge tower clock uses about 100 milliwatts for the clock movement.

Comment: Two pendulums (pendula?). When one needs to be pushed, it is later synchronized to the other. When the other needs to be pushed, the process is repeated.

Comment: The question specifies "Roman Technology" - Did the Romans know about the regularity of pendula or is that more of a Galilean/Newtonian thing?

Comment: @colmde, it's Galilean, first use around 1680, but that says as much about when accurate timekeeping actually became significant. It just didn't matter until open ocean navigation was important.

Comment: @Separatrix - I get you - of course the fictional emperor who wanted the accurate clock could have had his greatest philosophers research the idea and it would not be beyond the bounds of possibility that they could discover a pendulum ahead of (real-life) time...

Comment: I like this idea but having given it much thought I've decided that a pendulum is too advanced for my era.

Answer (score 6):

- Have the slaves build a large wheel, with an even number of carts evenly spread around it and a clear mark on it.
- Have the wheel installed with an horizontal axis, free of spinning.
- Have the slaves cut a number of stones, all from the same mine, all with the same shape and weight.
- Have the slaves carry the stones to the top of the wheel, where they will put one stone in each cart reaching the top.
- Have the slaves take away the stone from the cart when it reaches the bottom and carry the stone to the top.
- Define every round trip of the mark on the wheel your base time unit.

Comment: That is interesting - I like it. How would you prevent slaves putting stones onto the wheel too soon or too late?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, mechanical safety or slave supervisors equipped with whips

Comment: Why not just use bricks? (the Romans developed clay bricks by the time of the Empire and these would be easier to make more uniform)

Comment: I read it as "an even number of **cats**" which makes a good answer even better.

Comment: This machine works only against the friction in the wheel axis. After a day it will become faster or slower, depending on the wear.

Comment: A neat idea but doesn't seem like it would be very accuracte. The moment you switch slaves, their speed, carrying capacity, etc would change, as would there performance at different energy levels (fresh/tired/hungry/sleep deprived). But the real problem is the absurd limitations of the question.

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper, just build a queue of slaves and you can buffer some delay due to slaves. OP is not asking for atomic clock level of accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

With the mention of the analogue face, I'm going to assume they have a decent grasp of gearing. From there you need to control the speed that the slaves are rotating, for that you can use a simplified centrifuge governor.

[image: centrifuge governor]

Attach an arrow to the flyweights and have them point to a sweetspot chart and you could maintain a somewhat accurate fixed rotation speed.

Comment: So, basically, replace flyballs d(sub-b) and h(sub-s) with equally weighted slaves...

Comment: nah, rig it so if the slaves don't get the flyballs spinning fast enough, the flyballs his levers that cause whips to auto-lash the slaves pushing the main drive wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You build a release for polished, uniform stones on the top of a slope or fall, which is triggered by the stones hitting the ground.

Answer (score 1):

Have a giant isochronous curve (a curve that a falling object always takes the same time to traverse despite starting position, plug it into youtube to see toys based on them) with giant round rocks that roll  back and forth in it, attached to an arm that pushes the clock.

Over time the rocks will lose momentum due to friction and a slave will need to push the rock  back up to the top.

If there are a pair of curves, a well trained group of slaves can keep at least one ball rolling at all times. Naturally, when they release the rock, it's a dangerous business.

Answer (score 1):

#### How the Romans actually did it

A **clepsydra** is an ancient style of mechanical water clock used by the Greeks an Romans.  It used a float and gear system to turn a clock face.  Too keep it accurate, a slave would simply need to once a day empty the water from the float container, refill the water supply, and refill the float container until the time on the clepsydra matches the time on the sun dial.  A sun dial is always going to be accurate during the day, and the mechanical mechanism of the clepsydra allows you to estimate the current time from the last syncing so you can continue to tell what time it is when the sun is down or obscured.

[image]

> Water power, sand-timers, wound-springs etc. are not to be used directly to power the clock - just slave manual power. However an (unpowered?) mechanism will be need to regulate the machine.

**Frame Challenge: Water, sand, springs, etc. are not really a source of power for a clock, they are how the clock regulates its power to keep it from going too fast or too slow.  Without one of these, you have no clock.**

For example, my daughter has a model Da Vinci clock that uses a weight to turn it.  It works just fine if the weight is properly calibrated to the gearing, but if you add extra weight, it moves faster, less weight, it moves slower. So, using ancient technology, you need one of these "power sources" to regulate the time because direct human power will not be consistent enough. That said, when you use these things to regulate a clock the real power is actually coming from the person winding the spring, or moving the water or sand back up into the supply chamber.  In a small clock, this could be a job that only takes a person a few moments out of thier day, but the bigger your clock, the more energy it will take to reset the regulating medium.

So if we go with a clepsydra (but on a large scale), you could imagine a giant clock tower that raises above the level of the town cisterns so that it can be high enough to be seen from all around. But because of its height, you cant just passively fill its water supply from an aqueduct, you will need slaves to carry buckets of water  up the tower all day to fill the water supply to keep it running.  So it is literally powered by the work of slaves even though it is a water clock.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: You have a mechanism that stores built-up energy from the slaves, and uses that energy to power the clock. We already have this in the form of old wind-up clocks that rely on a person being willing to regularly wind them to function.

Answer (score 0):

Given the Era concerned the Emperor simply declares that '*money is no object*' i.e. the project is the Apollo moon mission of the the era concerned.

Slaves are simply tasked with implementing or assisting in the implementation/engineering of ever finer/more refined and accurate versions of both clocks. The exception being land holders in proportion to the  (e.g. clocks cast/etched in metal) until such time as they refine meticulously precise versions of both types of clock by trial and error.